# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-2.1.0) - Maintaining a Separate Log File

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 2.1.0.
Is it possible to maintain a separate log file for a specific API as required?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the APILogMessageHandler? I don't know whether you can create a separate log file from it, but you can add api specific logs. You just need to add following handler to the synapse api file generated in `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api` directory.

```
<handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.logging.APILogMessageHandler"/>
```

More information can be found in here. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Writing+Custom+Handlers

Answer (score 1):

Other than creating a custom log handler. You can also consider creating a separate service logger for that API as mentioned [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Enabling+per-Service+Logs+for+Services).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Even though the logs were enabled using the handler, the log4j configurations mentioned in the doc for writing a separate log seems incompatible because wso2am-2.1.0 uses an old log4j file instead of a log4j2 file.

Comment: @LilanMihiranga Sorry about that, I shared the wrong doc. Please refer this https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Enabling+Logs+for+Services